# error: getting assigned identities for pod in CREATED state failed - AKS AAD-Pod identity

Tags: azure-aks

I'm getting the below error for the pod in NMI logs for aks (1.14.8) with use of managed identity AAD-POD identity.
I have followed the steps as specified in https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity, except that we want to use the managed identity for the azure sql paas.
ref link: https://trstringer.com/connect-k8s-apps-msi/

```
E0618 17:19:40.762387 1 server.go:370] failed to get matching identities for pod: default/schedulerserviceapi-7fc4dc9547-95vbw, error: getting assigned identities for pod default/schedulerserviceapi-7fc4dc9547-95vbw in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s. Error: <nil>
```

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause for this is that your cluster service principal does not have the role `Managed Identity Operator`.

You can check the logs of the `mic` service, and look for the following log snippet "not have permission to perform action Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action'"

You can assign the role to the service principal using the CLI commands below:

```
# retrieve cluster service principal clientId ($SP_CLIENT_ID below)
az aks show -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query servicePrincipalProfile.clientId -o tsv

# assign role to SP
az role assignment create --role "Managed Identity Operator" --assignee $SP_CLIENT_ID  --scope /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP
```

ref: https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/issues/585

Comment: note that you may have to tweak the `az aks show` command if the cluster was created with a managed identity instead of a service principal

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your configured identities and bindings to match pods.

Read more: [Best Practices](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/best-practices/) and [Demo](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/demo/).

Find below example for pod using multiple AzureIdentities.

#### AzureIdentities

```yaml
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  name: az-id-1
spec:
  type: 0
  resourceID: <ResourceID of az-id-1>
  clientID: <ClientID of az-id-1>
```

```yaml
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  name: az-id-2
spec:
  type: 0
  resourceID: <ResourceID of az-id-2>
  clientID: <ClientID of az-id-2>
```

#### AzureIdentityBinding

```yaml
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: az-id-1-binding
spec:
  azureIdentity: az-id-1
  selector: az-id-combined
```

```yaml
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: az-id-2-binding
spec:
  azureIdentity: az-id-2
  selector: az-id-combined
```

#### Pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: az-id-combined
...
```

> Note: if you do not specify which managed identity to use (e.g. `az login -i`) then one of the managed identities matching the `aadpodidbinding` selector will be selected at random. To make sure the right managed identity is used for a particular workload, make sure you specify the managed identity's `clientId`  (e.g. `az login -i -u <CLIENT ID>`) or `resourceID` (e.g `az login -i -u <RESOURCE ID>`) when authenticating.

---

Check files at [`deploy/demo`](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/tree/v1.8.0/deploy/demo) for more examples.

---

To list all Azure identities in your cluster, run:

```
kubectl get azureidentities -A
```